# Using Elastic Query DSL in Kibana Discover to enable more_like_this etc

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

The Kibana documentation says:

> When lucene is selected as your query language you can also submit
>   queries using the Elasticsearch Query DSL.

However, whenever I try to enter such a query in the Discover pane, I get a parse error.  These are queries that work fine in the Dev Tools pane.

For example, if I try even a simple query like this:

```
{"query":{"match_phrase":{"summary":"stochastic noise"}}}
```

I get the following error:

```
Discover: [parsing_exception] no [query] registered for [query], with { line=1 & col=356 }    

Error: [parsing_exception] no [query] registered for [query], with { line=1 & col=356 }
    at respond (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:111:161556)
    at checkRespForFailure (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:111:160796)
    at http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:105:285566
    at processQueue (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:132456)
    at http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:133349
    at Scope.$digest (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:144239)
    at Scope.$apply (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:147018)
    at done (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:100026)
    at completeRequest (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:104697)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (http://<mydomain>:5601/bundles/vendors.bundle.js?v=16602:58:105435)
```

(I've removed my domain above and replaced with `<mydomain>`)

The above query works fine and returns results using cURL on the command line, or using

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "summary": "stochastic noise"
    }
  }
}
```

In the Dev Tools console.

I'm hoping to use the `more_like_this` query from the Discover panel, so (I think) I will need to use the Query DSL and not just use the straight lucene query syntax.  But if there's a way to use the specialty queries like that using straight lucene (or kuery) that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simply because the input box only supports whatever you include inside the `query` section, so if you input this, it will work:

```
{"match_phrase":{"summary":"stochastic noise"}}
```

It makes sense if you think about it, i.e. the `aggs` section makes no sense in the Discover pane and the `from/size` attributes are already taken care of by the default settings.

If you look at the full query DSL, you'll see that there are several sections: `query`, `aggs`, `from`, `size`, `_source`, `highlight`, etc. In the Discover pane, you should only specify whatever goes into the `query` section, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. Taking out the `query` part worked for me.  I'm not sure what you mean by the part of your reply about the `aggs` or `from/size` sections/attributes though.

Comment: If you look at the full query DSL, you'll see that there are several sections: `query`, `aggs`, `from`, `size`, `_source`, `highlight`, etc. All I'm saying is that in the Discover pane, you should only specify whatever goes into the `query` section.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It might be good to add that to the answer since comments sometimes get deleted.  After you do that, I'll accept the answer and award the bounty.

Comment: Fair enough, I've made the modification.